# Filtering a deeply nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, vuex

I have this array of objects with other arrays inside. Each object is a `partner` and each partner has 1 or several `industries` and `solutions`.

What I'm trying to do in the first instance is filter the `partners` by the selected `industry`. As an example, if the dropdown chosen was `Agency` then I only want to display the partners that have `Agency` as an option within their agency value.

I'm doing similar with a `specialty` but I only have a single value to contend with there

```
export function getBySpecialty(partners, specialty) {
    if (!specialty) return partners
    return partners.filter(partner => partner.specialty === specialty)
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing for a nested array?

```
var partners = [
  {
    id: 24,
    logo: null,
    name: "Partner 1",
    slug: "partner-1",
    excerpt:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet massa tellus, ac faucibus urna. Donec eget risus elit, quis pellentesque purus. Ut purus nibh, elementum ac ullamcorper consequat, vehicula et risus.",
    solutions: [
      {
        groupId: 2,
        id: 22,
        tempId: null,
        uid: "c2ebbe02-0028-4a2e-9233-41fbece3b3c7",
        fieldLayoutId: 20,
        structureId: null,
        contentId: 22,
        enabled: true,
        archived: false,
        siteId: 1,
        enabledForSite: true,
        title: "Solution 1",
        slug: "solution-1",
        uri: null,
        dateCreated: {
          date: "2018-08-22 02:25:48.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        dateUpdated: {
          date: "2018-08-22 02:25:48.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        root: null,
        lft: null,
        rgt: null,
        level: null,
        searchScore: null,
        awaitingFieldValues: false,
        propagating: false
      },
      {
        groupId: 2,
        id: 23,
        tempId: null,
        uid: "830d531e-807c-4aae-827d-170e21b72e32",
        fieldLayoutId: 20,
        structureId: null,
        contentId: 23,
        enabled: true,
        archived: false,
        siteId: 1,
        enabledForSite: true,
        title: "Solution 2",
        slug: "solution-2",
        uri: null,
        dateCreated: {
          date: "2018-08-22 02:25:52.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        dateUpdated: {
          date: "2018-08-22 02:25:52.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        root: null,
        lft: null,
        rgt: null,
        level: null,
        searchScore: null,
        awaitingFieldValues: false,
        propagating: false
      }
    ],
    specialty: "Behavioral Analytics",
    industries: [
      {
        groupId: 3,
        id: 15,
        tempId: null,
        uid: "87b17403-0aec-4ecf-a73f-c70aefb0c3ed",
        fieldLayoutId: 21,
        structureId: null,
        contentId: 15,
        enabled: true,
        archived: false,
        siteId: 1,
        enabledForSite: true,
        title: "Aerospace",
        slug: "aerospace",
        uri: null,
        dateCreated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 06:59:57.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        dateUpdated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 06:59:57.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        root: null,
        lft: null,
        rgt: null,
        level: null,
        searchScore: null,
        awaitingFieldValues: false,
        propagating: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    logo: null,
    name: "Partner 2",
    slug: "partner-2",
    excerpt:
      "A little excerpt about the partner",
    solutions: [
      {
        groupId: 2,
        id: 12,
        tempId: null,
        uid: "c93cb6c7-d44f-42cc-b170-8f0799b9a9f2",
        fieldLayoutId: 20,
        structureId: null,
        contentId: 12,
        enabled: true,
        archived: false,
        siteId: 1,
        enabledForSite: true,
        title: "Data Agility & Flexibility",
        slug: "data-agility-flexibility",
        uri: null,
        dateCreated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 06:59:34.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        dateUpdated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 06:59:34.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        root: null,
        lft: null,
        rgt: null,
        level: null,
        searchScore: null,
        awaitingFieldValues: false,
        propagating: false
      },
      {
        groupId: 2,
        id: 13,
        tempId: null,
        uid: "eabaf4aa-e69b-4e38-adac-df6ad9099eae",
        fieldLayoutId: 20,
        structureId: null,
        contentId: 13,
        enabled: true,
        archived: false,
        siteId: 1,
        enabledForSite: true,
        title: "Unifed Customer Data",
        slug: "unifed-customer-data",
        uri: null,
        dateCreated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 06:59:43.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        dateUpdated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 06:59:43.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        root: null,
        lft: null,
        rgt: null,
        level: null,
        searchScore: null,
        awaitingFieldValues: false,
        propagating: false
      }
    ],
    specialty: "Contextual Location",
    industries: [
      {
        groupId: 3,
        id: 15,
        tempId: null,
        uid: "87b17403-0aec-4ecf-a73f-c70aefb0c3ed",
        fieldLayoutId: 21,
        structureId: null,
        contentId: 15,
        enabled: true,
        archived: false,
        siteId: 1,
        enabledForSite: true,
        title: "Aerospace",
        slug: "aerospace",
        uri: null,
        dateCreated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 06:59:57.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        dateUpdated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 06:59:57.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        root: null,
        lft: null,
        rgt: null,
        level: null,
        searchScore: null,
        awaitingFieldValues: false,
        propagating: false
      },
      {
        groupId: 3,
        id: 16,
        tempId: null,
        uid: "cfe1349a-e7c4-420f-8db3-5a453243777f",
        fieldLayoutId: 21,
        structureId: null,
        contentId: 16,
        enabled: true,
        archived: false,
        siteId: 1,
        enabledForSite: true,
        title: "Agency",
        slug: "agency",
        uri: null,
        dateCreated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 07:00:09.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        dateUpdated: {
          date: "2018-08-21 07:00:09.000000",
          timezone_type: 3,
          timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"
        },
        root: null,
        lft: null,
        rgt: null,
        level: null,
        searchScore: null,
        awaitingFieldValues: false,
        propagating: false
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: just add another loop inside your filter and returns false if does not find the industry you want. you may need another loop for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gone with

```
export function getByIndustry(partners, industry) {
    if (!industry) return partners

    return partners.filter(partner => partner.industries.some(ind => ind.title === industry))
        .map(partner => partner)
}
```

Comment: amazing how explaining a problem can help clarify your thoughts to getting a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export function getByIndustry(partners, industryTitle) {
    if (!industryTitle) return partners
    return partners.filter(partner => partner.industries.filter(industry => industry.title === industryTitle).length)
}
```